# How can i add custom fields into the contact form 7

Tags: database, plugin-contact-form-7

I want to add additional fields into the contact us form. I already installed contact form 7 into my website,but now i want to add some more additional fields as per requirement. I also need to pull the information from the database to show into my website. Can anyone suggest me which plugin i will need to install for custom fields or any custom code i will need to add.  Thank you.

Comment: See if this helps: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-cf7-db/